# How can I install Groovy plugin in WebStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, webstorm

I'm developing with WebStorm. I want to have syntax highlighting for Jenkins Groovy pipelines.

It's possible to use InteliJ IDEA for editing Jenkinsfiles, but it's obviously inconvenient to switch back and forth between IDEs.

Can I install [Groovy plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/groovy) from IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition in WebStorm? If yes - how?

Comment: Did you have a look at the plugin manager? Do you find it in there?

Comment: Most likely not -- as it has dependencies on specific API/Java support that is not available in WebStorm and requires IntelliJ. If plugin is not listed in `Plugins | Browse repositories...` then it means it's either incompatible (not satisfying the dependency) or not published there. Considering that it's JetBrains' own plugin ... the 2nd option is not the case.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I didn't get that plugin to work either, but as a partial alternative, you can use this TextMate bundle: https://github.com/textmate/groovy.tmbundle

1. Download the repository (https://github.com/textmate/groovy.tmbundle/archive/master.zip)
2. Extract the zip file to some directory on your system
3. In WebStorm / IntelliJ / etc., go to File > Settings > Editor > TextMate bundles, click on the + sign and point it to the directory you just extracted to

Comment: Can you share a detail steps for that? I clicked the link you provided but didn't find anything to download.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I made the instructions more detailed as you requested

Comment: Thank very much. Imported. Then how can I apply them to the Jenkinsfile then?

Comment: You have to manually add Jenkinsfile as an extension in the TextMate bundle source. See `/Syntaxes/Groovy.tmLanguage`, after line 8. Here's Jetbrains' own documentation regarding this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/importing-textmate-bundles.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Do you know why there is no "Files supported via TextMate bundles" among the "recognized files types" dialog in my webstorm?

Comment: You're welcome! Not sure about that one; I don't see it either. Could be a bug, a removed feature or a new feature that hasn't been released yet.

Comment: Yes it does! That file types dialog entry is not strictly necessary. By default, after importing the TextMate bundle, it'll highlight `.groovy` and `.gvy` files. By adding a `Jenkinsfile` entry to the file mentioned earlier and then reimporting the bundle you can make it highlight files named `Jenkinsfile`.

Comment: Thank you again! Highlighting works! It would be better if it can fold/unfold the code blocks.

Comment: If you are using a non-default theme, while you are in File > Settings > Editor > TextMate bundles, you'll need to map the new theme.  And it will not take effect until you restart the IDE.

Comment: WebStorm now officially supports Groovy via the TextMate Plugin, see [issue WEB-43111](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-43111). So, there's no need anymore for an additionally download like instructed above.